# Can I initialize object of different types in an if statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, initialization, language-lawyer, declaration

I know I can write

```cpp
if (int a = 1; /* whatever */) {}
```

and even

```cpp
if (int a = 1, b{3}; /* whatever */) {}
```

but how can I declare, say, `a` of type `int` and `b` of type `std::string`?

Such a thing doesn't work:

```cpp
if (auto a = 1, b{"ciaos"s}; /* whatever */) {}
```

I've not included a standard, because I'm interested in the answer in general, even though realistically I'd make use of the answer in the context of [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).

And, if such a thing is not possible, is there any precise reason why (hence [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer))?

Comment: Tha answer is no but it's not the `if` that prohibits it. If you want to declare multiple instances, they need to really be of the same type. `int x, char y;` does not work either

Comment: you are only allowed one variable declaration statement in a if statement and each variable declaration statement can only declare a single type.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I didn't say you couldn't.  I said you can only have a single type.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah... ok, poor reading on my part.... cleaning up ..

Comment: @TedLyngmo - They are all part of the same simple-declaration. Nathan is correct. Only one declaration is allowed.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes, I misunderstood Nathan's point and removed my comment a few minutes ago :-) Sloppy reading on my part.

Comment: Dup of [What happens when one uses auto with two declarations in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778604/what-happens-when-one-uses-auto-with-two-declarations-in-c11)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are only allowed one variable declaration statement in a if statement and each variable declaration statement can only declare a single type. This is convered in [[stmt.if]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.if#3) where is shows the grammar for the if statement you are trying to use is

```
if constexpr(opt) ( init-statement condition ) statement
```

and [`init-statement`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.pre#nt:init-statement) can be a [`simple-declaration`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.pre#nt:simple-declaration) and that contains a [`init-declarator-list`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.decl.general#nt:init-declarator-list) which only allows a single [`declarator`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.decl.general#nt:declarator).  Normally this means just a single type, but pointers (*) and references (&) get applied to the variable name, not the type name so you can have `T`, `T*`, and/or `T&` variables declared in a single `init-declarator-list` i.e., `int a = 42, *b = &a, &c = a;`

As a workaround, you can leverage [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) and [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (to reduce verbosity) in conjunction with [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) to get a syntax like

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    if (auto [a, b] = std::tuple{42, "string"s}; a)
    {
        std::cout << b;
    }
}
```

which outputs

```
string
```

Comment: fwiw, CTAD isnt strictly needed, only for less verbosity

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it's definitely welcome, though.

Comment: The type is part of the `decl-specifier-seq`, not the `init-declarator-list`. The declarators are the variables. And they can further derive from the type (`int i, *p;`)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yeah, was trying to figure out how to word that.  I think I do a better job of that now.